# Photoshop files vs PIL psd_tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to build a file finder, and as far as the file types listed in `extensions` go, I'm doing well so far, however, as soon as i get to the challenging part of trying to get meta data for *.psd files (see section marked with ### PROBLEMATIC CODE BEGINS HERE ###), I'm met with an error message, that I cannot solve by simple googling.

At first glance it appeared to be a straight shot using psd_tools.PSDImage, alas I get an error:

```
raise Error("This is not a PSD or PSB file")
psd_tools.exceptions.Error: This is not a PSD or PSB file
```

In and by itself, that is peculiar to me, seeing as `elif filename.lower().endswith('.psd'):` ought to indicate that we're in fact dealing with a *.psd.
I will of course supply the bulk of the error message if needed; just let me know :)

Any experts out there whom would care to shed some light on this conundrum?

Here's my code in all it's dubious glory:

```
#!/src/bin/env/python3

import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
from psd_tools import PSDImage
import exiftool

extensions = [
    '.jpg',
    '.jpeg',
    '.tif',
    '.tiff',
    '.png',
    '.bmp',
    '.gif',
    '.raw'
    ]

greatest_hits = []

drive_name = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(drive_name):
    for filename in filenames:
        for extension in extensions:
            if filename.lower().endswith(extension):
                current = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                file_weight = str(os.path.getsize(current)/1000) + ' kB'
                im = Image.open(current)
                file_width, file_height = im.size
                # print('{:50s}{size:>10}{width:>8}{height:>8}'.format(filename, size=file_weight, width=file_width, height=file_height))
                dict_x = {'name':filename, 'path':current, 'size':file_weight, 'width': file_width, 'height': file_height}
                greatest_hits.append(dict_x)
            ### PROBLEMATIC CODE BEGINS HERE! ###
            elif filename.lower().endswith('.psd'):
                psd_im = PSDImage.load(current)
                print(psd.header)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this link interesting: https://www.pythoncentral.io/finding-duplicate-files-with-python/
Also, you may want to read up on https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/ if you really must know what hashing is. And you do.

Using hashlib one may sort files using unique, fixed length sequences (vars), which ensures that a file A and another file B are identical even if file B has been renamed. Very clever. Come back in a couple of days and accept this answer as a feasible solution if you like :)